# How to disable elasticity property of list view in Windows Phone 8.1..?

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I am using the ListView control of Windows Phone 8.1. I am using data binding to populate the list items. It works fine. But I am able to pull the list down from the top( ie..When we pull down the list, first item comes down and  the background color can be seen, and when released it goes back to normal view). As of I understand this is the default behavior of ListView.

```
 How can I change this behavior..?
 It should not be rigid but scroll should end where the list item ends, not
 more than that...I don't require any elasticity property
```